# Drop in quality of texture rendering using OpenGL ES2.0

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, graphics2d

I'm drawing a texture on to a square using OpenGL ES2.0 [ ANdroid ] . The texture scrolls infinitely in vertical direction.

The rendering quality drops very rapidly after a few frames and the texture quality is deteriorated.

Screenshot #1 
[image: Initial Image]

Screenshot #2
[image: After a few frames]

How to correct this issue?

Code:

```
package gamedev.soursugar.infinitescroll;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

/**
 * Created by soursugar on 19/12/14.
 */
public class Background {

    private final String vertexShaderCode =
            "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;"      +
                    "attribute vec4 vPosition;"     +
                    "attribute vec2 TexCoordIn;"    +
                    "varying vec2 TexCoordOut;"     +
                    "void main() {"                 +
                    "   gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;"  +
                    "   TexCoordOut = TexCoordIn;"  +
                    "}";

    private final String fragmentShaderCode =
            "precision mediump float;"  +
                    "uniform vec4 vColor;"      +
                    "uniform sampler2D TexCoordIn;" +
                    "uniform float scroll;" +
                    "varying vec2 TexCoordOut;" +
                    "void main() {" +
                    "   gl_FragColor = texture2D(TexCoordIn, vec2(TexCoordOut.x, TexCoordOut.y + scroll));" +
                    "}";


    private int[] textures = new int[1];

    private byte[] indices = {
            0, 1, 2,
            0, 2, 3
    };

    private float[] texture = {
            0.0f, 1.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f
    };

    private float[] vertices = {
            -1f, -1f, 0f,
            -1f, 1f, 0f,
            1f, 1f, 0f,
            1f, -1f, 0f
    };

    private final FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private final ByteBuffer indexBuffer;
    private final FloatBuffer textureBuffer;

    private final int mProgram;
    private int mPositionHandle;
    private int mMVPMatrixHandle;

    static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
    static final int COORDS_PER_TEXTURE = 2;
    private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4;
    private final int textureStride = COORDS_PER_TEXTURE * 4;

    private float scroll = 0.00f;

    public Background() {
        ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();

        byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texture.length * 4);
        byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        textureBuffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
        textureBuffer.put(texture);
        textureBuffer.position(0);

        indexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length);
        indexBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        indexBuffer.put(indices);
        indexBuffer.position(0);

        int vertexShader = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        GLES20.glShaderSource(vertexShader, vertexShaderCode);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(vertexShader);

        int fragmentShader = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        GLES20.glShaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentShaderCode);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

        mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader);

        GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);

    }

    private void reloadVertexBuffer() {
        vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);
    }

    public void loadTexture(int texture, Context context, int width, int height) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        float w = 0.75f;

        try{
            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inScaled=false;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getAssets().open("background.png"));
            w = (1.0f/height)*width;
            Log.d("Width", String.valueOf(w));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception from SourSugar", "Error in decoding stream");
        }

        vertices[0] = -w;
        vertices[3] = -w;
        vertices[6] = w;
        vertices[9] = w;
        reloadVertexBuffer();

        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);

        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_REPEAT);

        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
        bitmap.recycle();
    }

    public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix, int frameCount) {
        //if(frameCount==25 || frameCount==50)
            //scroll = 0f;

        scroll -= 0.005f;
        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

        mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);


        int vsTextureCoord = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "TexCoordIn");


        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, vertexStride, vertexBuffer);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(vsTextureCoord, COORDS_PER_TEXTURE, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, textureStride, textureBuffer);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(vsTextureCoord);


        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);

        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
        int fsTexture = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "TexCoordOut");
        int fsScroll = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "scroll");

        GLES20.glUniform1i(fsTexture, 0);
        GLES20.glUniform1f(fsScroll, scroll);

        mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");

        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);

        GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indexBuffer);
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show your codes?

Comment: It could be a floating point precision issue in your fragment shader with your texture co-ordinates losing precision as the values get larger as you scroll down.

Comment: Code added. Texture coordinates are subtracted by 0.005 in every draw().

Comment: @RajathS: 0.005 = (2 * (5*2)^n)^-1 = 2^-1 * 2^-n * 5^-n. The factor 5^-n can not be represented with a finite amount of bits. Hence you're running into a precision issue.

Comment: One more question: In my code, I'm correcting for the aspect ratio manually. But, I've read on many tutorials that OpenGL auto normalizes the display coordinates to [-1,1]. If I use my vertex coordinates as -1 to 1, the picture is drawn out of the bounds of the display. What could be causing this?

Comment: It's probably the matrix transform in your vertex shader that is causing that. Although it's hard to answer that exactly without seeing how you calculate mvpMatrix. If you change your vertex shader code to pass the vertices through untransformed (i.e. gl_Position = vPosition;) then using vertex co-ordinates of -1 to 1 should fit the corners of the display as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is related to this line in your fragment shader:

```
"gl_FragColor = texture2D(TexCoordIn, vec2(TexCoordOut.x, TexCoordOut.y + scroll));"
```

Roughly speaking, floating point numbers can represent either small numbers accurately, or large numbers inaccurately. When you add two floating point numbers together, the result will usually have the accuracy of the larger-magnitude (less accurate) of the two. So when the value of *scroll* gets too large in magnitude, the accuracy of the texture coordinate (TexCoordOut.y + scroll) is reduced.

You can fix this by changing the Java code to make your scroll value wrap around in the range of 0.0 - 1.0

```
scroll -= 0.005f;
if(scroll < 0.0f)
    scroll += 1.0f;
```

Since you are making your texture wrap around in T, you can discard the integer part and it won't make any difference.